# Chart Control .NET not showing all data

Tags: c#, windows, charts

I have used .net chart control in a website. When I launch it with big amount of data, the chart does not show all data. If any one can help me find out if there is a way to show all the data I have. And If I can show the legends above the chart. Please reply.

```
Series series = new Series(name);
series.ChartType = (type == 1) ? SeriesChartType.Column : SeriesChartType.Pie; 
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> item in xy) 
{ 
      series.Points.AddXY(item.Key,item.Value);
}
```

Comment: What exactly chart does not show?

Comment: Thanks for your reply
well when I provide about 50 data in x axis, it is showing only 4/5 of them. But I want it show all of them and I also need to find out if there is way so that I can set the legend above the chart control

Comment: Please add some code to your post.

Comment: Series series = new Series(name);
        series.ChartType = (type == 1) ? SeriesChartType.Column : SeriesChartType.Pie;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> item in xy)
        {
            series.Points.AddXY(item.Key,item.Value);
            
        } <br/>These are to add series to the charts

Comment: @MehbubeArman: You should edit your question to add the code example, instead of putting it here as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You should set maximunm and minimum values
 Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Maximum = vMaxY
 Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Minimum = vMaxY